# Laravel Passport createToken method not giving me access_token. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: laravel, token, access-token, laravel-passport

**All of configuration is right, but does not work.**

My controller code is:

```
 $appUser = User::create([
                'name' => $user->name,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'password' => Hash::make(Str::random(8)),
            ]);

return $passportToken = $appUser->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
```

and response code from this URL (http://localhost:8000/api/authorize/github/callback?code=6ba82d59f00fdb1ad5c9) is:

```
{
  "name": "Token Name",
  "abilities": [
    "*"
  ],
  "tokenable_id": 1,
  "tokenable_type": "App\\Models\\User",
  "updated_at": "2021-09-19T05:10:00.000000Z",
  "created_at": "2021-09-19T05:10:00.000000Z",
  "id": 3
}
```

Comment: your code should work normally , are you sure you are requesting the prober URL?

Comment: @MoussabKbeisy, Yes

Comment: @Eahiya Does field `accessToken` exist in User table? Could you please share User model?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG Yes there is no accessToken column 

/ table
 $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

Answer (score 2):

By Default User Model use HasApiToken provided by Laravel\**Sanctum**\HasApiTokens trait, please check User Model and if it point to Sanctum update it to use Laravel\**Passport**\HasApiTokens;

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Passport uses its own database migration directory, so you should migrate your database after installing the Laravel Passport package. The Passport migrations will create the tables your application needs to store clients and access tokens:

```
php artisan migrate
```

If you have any problems, tell me.

Comment: i have migrated passport table but still not working

Comment: Did you install Laravel Passport using `composer require laravel/passport`?